# Claiming Bitcoin Cash From Mycelium

Tags: wallet, blockchain-fork

How do I claim my bitcoin cash (BCH) from a **single address** Mycelium wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to export your Mycelium master seed:

[image]

[detailed description](https://support.mycelium.com/hc/en-us/articles/207045535-How-do-I-make-a-backup-)

Then you need to import the master seed into the bitcoin cash version of electrum wallet, which is the electron wallet. This can be done by choosing "BIP39 Seed" in the options, during the import.

[image]

see this [post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1813651.0) for details.

> Note: For security reasons you should empty your bitcoin wallet before
>   claiming your bitcoin cash.

Answer (score 1):

You simply import the private key of the single adress wallet into a bitcoin cash wallet such as https://electroncash.org/

Comment: That doesn't help. Exporting the private key from Mycelium is extremely hard, if not impossible.

Comment: Actually I finally managed to claim the BCH from the *single address* mycelium wallet. Using electron cash and sweeping the private key! Thank you. It *is* possible!